# Jquery uploadifiy realtime update

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify

How can I send some parameters, that they aren't defined when the page loads, I have a select box, and I also need to send to PHP, the selected value?So here my code

```
var _data = $('#art:selected').val();

$('#art').live('change', function () {
    $selected = $(":selected", this);
    id = $selected.val();
    _data = id;
});

$('.vla').live('click', function () {

    $("#uploadify").uploadifyUpload();
    return false;
});

$("#uploadify").uploadify({
    'uploader': '/extra/flash/uploadify.swf',
    'script': '/admin/uploads/artistsphotos',
    'scriptData': { 'title': _data },
    'cancelImg': '/images/cancel.png',
    'folder': '/img/artists',
    'queueID': 'fileQueue',
    'auto': false,
    'multi': true,
    'onComplete': function (a, b, c, d, e) {
        console.log(d);
    },
    'onAllComplete': function (event, data) {
        //something here  
        //alert(data);
    }
});
```

The field has the id #art, and I'm trying to get the selected value when I submit, any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

What I did when i encountered this problem was that I made a separate form to handle the settings and had it submitted to a processing script that stored the data as session data and then accessed that session data from the upload processing script.  I don't know if this is the best way to handle it but it works.

You could also use the onComplete function to collect the form data and send it to a script to be processed.  the Oncomplete function has access to the file information for the file that just finished uploading.

Comment: Yeah, I will try this thing out.